# Transfering all photos from old iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, photos

I have an iPad 3rd gen (running iOS 9.3.6) and the new iPad 7th gen. I am trying to get all the pictures from the old iPad to the new. When I turn on iCloud for photos I get the following error: “

> Photos and Videos Synced from iTunes will be Removed

The problem is that I no longer have the PC which I used to sync. The only copy of all these photos is on the iPad and I am having a difficult time transferring them off the iPad.

To summarize, I want to get all the pictures from an old iPad. On the old iPad I have photos from the following sources:

- Import from iTunes.
- Import from a digital camera using the converter.
- Pictures taken with the iPad.

I do not have easy access to a Mac or PC.

Comment: Can you not access all the photos to the when you connect ipad to PC over USB? It should open a Allow Photos dialog when you connect it on ipad. Also you can always try the apple support for these types of questions in the Support App.

Comment: Can you download google photos and use that? I don't know if your iPad will be able to handle it, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get access to a Mac or a PC, you should try the [iMazing](https://imazing.com/) application.

It allows you to selectively copy data from your iPad. You should be able to get all photos from the Photos app. I believe iMazing can also copy individual apps and their data from one device to another.

The iMazing application can also create backups and lets you browse those backups. Make a backup. Save it to a USB pen drive. Whatever method you use to transfer photos from your old iPad to the new iPad, that USB stick will be your safety net. Keep it around until you are sure the new iPad has all the photos.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the camera connector ( https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter ) + 30 pin cable (the one that fits your older iPad) + lightning cable (the cable for your new iPad).

- Camera connector goes to your iPad.
- Use the extra lightning slot to
  provide power to the iPad/connector.
- Use your 30 pin cable from the
  old iPad to plug that into the USB-A slot.
- Unlock new iPad and go to
  photos.
- Unlock old iPad.
- They may ask if you want to "trust." Tap in
  passcode to say yes.
- New iPad will show "import" tab/button.
- Import
  away.

May take some time depending on # of photos and videos. That is why you have it plugged into power.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, create an Outlook account and install on each iPad the OneDrive app.
Turn on each iPad the OneDrive Camera upload to ON. This might be the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using PhotoSync.

https://www.photosync-app.com/home.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. [Backup the old iPad using iCloud](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/back-up-iphone-iph3ecf67d29/ios) and then [restore the backup onto the new one](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/restore-or-set-up-your-ios-or-ipados-device-mm7e756df7fd/icloud). This will delete everything on the new iPad and is not recommended **but you don't need a Mac or PC**.
2. Use a Mac or PC to do it

I am going to assume you are using a Mac for these instructions:

1. Plug in your old iPad via USB
2. [Import the Photos using either Photos.app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302) or Image Capture.app (I prefer the latter)
3. Transfer the Photos using iCloud Photos on the Mac or by other means

I prefer using the tools on macOS instead of third party software (as another answer suggested) because it usually works better and there is less risk of corruption.

I find iTunes has a lot of issues and is a bit more complicated which is why I suggested Image Capture and Photos over it.